# Weaken Ramsey's Number $R(4,4)$ from $18$ to $20$ , for a simpler proof.

Tags: combinatorics, alternative-proof, pigeonhole-principle

> Given $20$ people. Show that there exists a group of $4$ which either everyone in the group know each other, or no one know each other at all.

Ok, so I've read and found that $R(4,4) = 18$ on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramsey%27s_theorem)

And I found that they've prove by bounding the $R(4,4)$ value using recurrence relation $R(r, s) ≤ R(r − 1, s) + R(r, s − 1) − 1$ , which yields $R(4,4) \leq 18$. Then, they construct an counter-example ([here](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/arithmetic/combinatorics/Ramsey44.shtml)) and show that $R(4,4) \gt 17$. Hence, $R(4,4) = 18$.

Now, I've wonder , if we weaken the value to $20$ , can we prove the question above by using some elementary knowledge, such as pigeonhole principal?

Thanks in advance!

PS : If this question was asked already, please show me the link. Thank you!

Comment: Essentially yes. The recurrence relation arises from induction and Pigeonhole principle, so just follow that. You could even do $ R(4, 4) \leq 18$ that way.

Comment: Thanks @CalvinLin

Comment: You can use R(3,3)=6 to prove in any 7 vertex graph there are at least 2 monochromatic triangles ...

Comment: In fact you can iterate to 8 vertices giving 3 ( just leave out a vertex from each previous triangle and the remaining 6 need another) ... This iterates more in theory by 20 there are 15 monochromatic triangles. At least in a 2 color case that means 8 are one of the colors by pigeonhole principle.